# Getting an Array from user? C programming

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

My console keeps on crashing after entering a few numbers. I am trying to get an array of 10 numbers from the user thru the console and then taking count of positives, negatives, evens, and odds. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int pos, neg, even, odd;
int nums[10];
printf("Give me 10 numbers: ");


pos = neg = even = odd = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    scanf(" %d", nums[i]);
    if(nums[i] > 0){
        pos++;
        if(nums[i] % 2 == 0){
            even++;
        }
        else{
            odd++;
        }
    }
    else{
        neg++;
    }
}

printf("Positives: %d, Negatives: %d, Evens: %d, Odds: %d\n", pos, neg, even, odd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you get any warnings about how you use `scanf`?

Comment: Also, your negative numbers aren't counting towards your even or odd count. Move your modulo one `if` out. And 0 will count as odd by your logic above (remember, 0 is neither positive nor negative, it will need its own case).

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 scanf(" %d", nums[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %d", &(nums[i]));
```

or,

```
scanf(" %d", nums+i);
```

as you need to pass the pointer to variable as the format specifier's argument in `scanf()` .

To elaborate, `%d` expects a pointer to `int` and what you're supplying is an `int` variable. it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

1. Always check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure proper scanning.
2. `int main()` should be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.

Comment: ... or just pass `num + i`. Which at least is fewer typing.

Comment: You don't need the extra parentheses in `scanf(" %d", &(nums[i]));` - it can just be `scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);`.

Comment: @Paul R Curious you mentioned no need for `()` yet did not mention about no need for `" "` in `" %d"`.  --> `scanf("%d", &nums[i]);`

Comment: @chux: yes, maybe not needed in this instance, but often useful for flushing trailing newlines or other white space from previous reads.

Comment: @Paul R `scanf("%d", &nums[i]);`  flushes "trailing newlines or other white space from previous reads" even without the leading`" "` in the format.

Comment: @chux: so are you saying that there is never a good reason to prefer `scanf(" %d", ...);` over `scanf("%d", ...);` ?

Comment: @Paul R The functionality of `" %d"` vs `"%d"`  is nearly identical. Like  `&(nums[i])` vs `&nums[i]`, should the simpler one be preferred? There a small difference when an `int` is not scanned.  `" %d"` does consume leading whitespace  vs `"%d"` which _might_ consume leading whitespace.  I've noticed many implementations do not conform to the C spec here, unget-ing more than 1 whitespace `char` to `stdin`.

Comment: @chux: thanks for the clarification - always good to have one's preconceptions challenged - I may have to play with this later as I'd always assumed that the `" %d"` trick was a useful way to flush white space, particularly an unwanted newline from a previous read.

Comment: @Paul R Note: all specifiers, except `%c %n %[` consume optional leading WS.

Answer (score 0):

Modify scanf like `scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf(" %d", nums[i]);
```

Scanf expects a pointer to a location to write to, and you're not giving it one.

Change your scanf to:

```
scanf(" %d", &(nums[i]));
```

to make your program work.

With this change I tested your program with `stdin` of

> 20 10 9 1 39 1 2 2 31 1

And recieved output:

> Give me 10 numbers: Positives: 10, Negatives: 0, Evens: 4, Odds: 6

[ideone](https://ideone.com/JsNDhL) of the thing for your testing purposes.

Comment: You don't need the extra parentheses in `scanf(" %d", &(nums[i]));` - it can just be `scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);`.

Comment: @PaulR Thats true. I usually like to put them anyways, but it works without.

Answer (score 0):

When `scanf` is usedto convert numbers, it expects a pointer to the corresponding type as argument, in your case `int *`:

```
scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);
```

This should get rid of your crash. `scanf` has a return value, namely the number of conversions made or the special value `EOF` to indicate the end of input. Please check it, otherwise you can't be sure that you have read a valid number.

When you look at your code, you'll notice that you don't need an array. Afterreading the number, you don't do aything with the array. You just keep a tally of odd, even and so on numbers. That means you just need a single integer to store the current number. That also extends your program nicely to inputs of any length.

Here's a variant that reads numbers until the end of input is reached (by pressing Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z) or until a non-number is entered, e.g. `"stop"`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    int num;

    while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
        count++;

        if (num > 0) pos++;
        if (num < 0) neg++;

        if (num % 2 == 0) even++;
        if (num % 2 != 0) odd++;
    }

    printf("%d numbers, of which:\n", count);
    printf("    %d positive\n", pos);
    printf("    %d negative\n", neg);
    printf("    %d even\n", even);
    printf("    %d odd\n", odd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf(" %d", nums[i]);` to `scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);`, because `scanf()` needs addresses. The parentheses around `nums[i]` isn't necessary, and may effect readability.

Also note that `0` is even, but not negative.

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf` statement after for loop to

```
scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);
```